# Conditional subsetting from dataframe with multiple conditions

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

In my data.frame below, I want to subset all rows for which `group == 0` AND all 3 years of 2017, 2018, and 2019 are also included.

**Desired output** in the example below is the information on rows 4, 5, and 6.

I have tried the following solution with no success. Is there a quick fix in **BASE R**?

```
dat <- data.frame(group = c(0,0,1, 0,0,0, 1, 1, 1), 
       year = rep(2017:2019, 3))

subset(dat, group == 0 & year == 2017 & year == 2018 & year == 2019)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the OP wanted to treat the 'group' adjacent unique

```
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)
dat %>%
   group_by(grp = rleid(group)) %>%
   filter(all(2017:2019 %in% year), group == 0) %>%
   ungroup %>%
   select(-grp)
# A tibble: 3 x 2
#  group  year
#  <dbl> <int>
#1     0  2017
#2     0  2018
#3     0  2019
```

---

Or in `base R` with `rle`

```
grp <- with(rle(dat$group), rep(seq_along(values), lengths))
subset(dat, as.logical(ave(year,  grp, FUN = 
    function(x) all(2017:2019 %in% x)) ) & group == 0)
#  group year
#4     0 2017
#5     0 2018
#6     0 2019
```

Comment: @rnorouzian i was thinking that you wanted to reduce the `==` number of times

Comment: @rnorouzian do you need `subset(dat, as.logical(ave(year, grp, FUN = function(x) all(c(2017,2019) %in% x)) ) & group == 0 & year %in% c(2017, 2019))`

Comment: @rnorouzian or another optoiin is to first do the `filter` i.e.  `dat1 <- subset(dat, year %in% c(2017, 2019))` and then apply the code in the solution